# Minimum value for a multiplication in an equation with 2 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

How can I find out the minimum value of $mn$ where $m$ and $n$ must be natural numbers, bigger than $0$, from the equation $$60m+3n=2mn$$

Comment: This the final equation from a physics problem and thank you but 0 is not a solution for the problem. I should have specified natural numbers bigger than 0, my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By AM-GM $$2mn\geq2\sqrt{60m\cdot3n}=2\sqrt{180mn},$$ which gives $$mn\geq180.$$ the equality occurs for $60m=3n,$ 
which gives $$(m,n)=(3,60).$$
Id est, $180$ is the minimal value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $m,n>0$

$$30/n+3/2m=1$$

Now use AM GM inequality

Answer (score 0):

First we see that $n=2k$ so we have $$30m+3k=2mk$$ so $k=2l$ and now we have $$15m+3l=2ml$$Now we have $$l ={15m\over 2m-3}$$ so $$2m-3\mid 15$$ so $$2m-3\in \{1,3,5,15,-1,-3,-5,-15\}$$

so $$2m\in \{2,4,6,8,18\}$$
so $m\in \{1,2,3,4,9\}$ and respectively $l\in\{-15,30,15,12,9\}$. So the minimum value of $mn = 4ml = 180$.